# why does pandas violate its own warnings?

Tags: python, pandas, warnings

I have some code dealing with pandas DataFrames.

When I run this code I get a plethora of `SettingsWithCopyWarning`s.

All of the warnings are coming from the pandas codebase itself though. This baffles me.

I've updated pandas so I don't think it's a version issue.

Am I using pandas incorrectly? Does everyone get these warnings? If so, should I turn them off? How would I do that?

Here's an example of the output I get as my program is running (it doesn't cause my program to stop):

```
...
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:362: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self.obj[key] = _infer_fill_value(value)
...
...
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:543: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self.obj[item] = s
...
```

I assume the `pandas\core\indexing.py:543` is referring to a line in the pandas codebase which is violating this guideline and causing the error? Is this assumption correct? I assume this because it makes no reference to any line in my codebase.

If that assumption is not correct I can provide lines from my codebase.

Thank you.

EDIT:

My version of Pandas:

```
>pip show pandas
Name: pandas
Version: 0.23.4
```

My version of python:

```
>python
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:22:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

My code below is not verbatim because it's long and complicated, but I think I've pulled out a typical example of what may cause this.

My code example:

```
# I create a dask workflow and send a dataframe through it. 
def binning_workflow(df: pd.DataFrame, bins: dict) -> pd.DataFrame:
    workflow = {
    ...
    'bin_customs_osha': (bin_customs_data, 'bin_something_else',),
    ...
    }
    return dask.multiprocessing.get(workflow, 'merge_binned_columns_10')

# a function called during dask workflow 
def bin_customs_data(df):
    cols = ['OSHA_GRAVITY', 'OSHA_OPEN_DATE',]
    for v in cols:
        if v in df.columns:
            df.loc[:, v] = df[v].apply(lambda x: 'unknown' if x == -1 else x).astype(str)
    df.loc[:, 'OSHA_PENALTIES_IND_BIN'] = 0
    df.loc[df['NAICS_SECTOR_DESCRIPTION'] != 'Construction', 'OSHA_PENALTIES_IND_BIN'] = df['OSHA_PENALTIES_IND'].astype(str) + ' not const'
    return df
```

I just find it strange that the warning makes no mention of my code, how am I supposed to know from where the warning arises?

Comment: While the warning may arise in that part of the library, it is still caused by a line in *your* code; without seeing that code, we can't tell if it's bad or good. But, some of these warnings are overzealous, and can actually be ignored; but generally, try to avoid them.

Comment: @9769953 I added my versions and a bit of my code

Comment: CAn you please try changing this df.loc[:, v] = df[v].apply(lambda x: 'unknown' if x == -1 else x).astype(str) to df[v] = df[v].apply(lambda x: 'unknown' if x == -1 else x).astype(str)

Comment: Or even `df.loc[df[v] == -1, v] = 'unknown'`.

Comment: @NAGA I tried that, but it didn't help, thanks though

Comment: @StevenRumbalski thanks, I tried that, and it simplified my code, thanks, but it didn't fix the issue. I'll probably just ignore the warnings for now